# Get values from entity class

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, telerik

I have a method that has min and max values hard code how could I the values from a entity model class? I want to be about to look up the min and max value so they are not in the code. I have include my code and entity class and sql table.

thanks

code:

```
        protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        //Is it a GridDataItem
        if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
        {
            //Get the instance of the right type
            GridDataItem dataBoundItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;

            //Check the formatting condition
            if (dataBoundItem["sample_hour"].Text == "4hr YP")
            {
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["ph"], 5.72f, 4.75f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["brix"], 17.35f, 22.36f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["temp"],89.08f, 90.97f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["bud"], 3.12f, 40.76f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["cell_count"], 41.24f, 177.70f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["viability"], 69.18f, 103.08f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["dp4"], 2.55f, 10.89f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["dp3"], 1.41f, 6.05f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["maltose"], 0.41f, 8.28f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["glucose"], -0.26f, 6.69f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["lactic_acid"], 0.01f, 0.12f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["glycerol"], 0.33f, 0.57f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["acetic_acid"], 0.07f, 0.17f);
                SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["ethanol"], .005f, 1.15f);
            }

        }
    }
    private void SetFormatting(TableCell cell, float minValue, float maxValue)
    {
        float value = float.Parse(cell.Text);

        if (value < minValue || value > maxValue)
        {
            cell.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            cell.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            cell.Font.Bold = true;
        }
    }
```

Entity model class:

```
    public partial class tbl_ferm_validation
{
    public int validation_id { get; set; }
    public string sample_type { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> val_hi { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> val_hihi { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> val_lo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> val_lolo { get; set; }
}
```

}

Sql table:

```
1   ph  5.7200  NULL    4.7500  NULL
2   brix    17.3500 NULL    22.3600 NULL
3   temp    89.0800 NULL    90.9700 NULL
4   level   94.8100 NULL    88.1000 NULL
5   bud 3.1200  NULL    40.7600 NULL
6   cell count  41.2400 NULL    177.7000    NULL
7   viability   69.1800 NULL    103.0800    NULL
8   dp4 2.5500  NULL    10.8900 NULL
9   dp3 1.4100  NULL    6.0500  NULL
10  maltose 0.4100  NULL    8.2800  NULL
11  glucose -0.2600 NULL    6.6900  NULL
12  lactic acid 0.0100  NULL    0.1200  NULL
13  glycerol    0.3300  NULL    0.5700  NULL
14  acetic acid 0.0700  NULL    0.1700  NULL
15  ethanol 0.0050  NULL    1.1500  NULL
```